# Adobe Air - Starling/Feathers - Text Input without OS level hooks (aka StageText)?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, starling-framework

Long story short, I seem to always be running into unpredictable [StageText](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StageText.html) functionality in Adobe AIR applications.  I want to avoid triggering the OS native input fields and emulate that functionality in a Feathers/Actionscript component directly.

I've incorporated an on-screen keyboard purely in Feathers and implemented a Button subclass that acts like a basic text input.  When the user clicks the button, the on-screen keyboard is displayed and hardware keyboard KEYUP's are intercepted and used to dynamically update the button label attribute.

That all works well enough, but of course I have no flashing cursor or text selectability in my current rudimentary widget.  I can continue along my current path and manually implement the rest of what I need, but wanted to ask if anyone has seen or implemented a 'native acting' non-native text input widget in the Feathers/Starling/Actionscript tech stack?  (Google seems to say no, but I'm hoping that's wrong.  Surely I'm not the only one that thinks AIR's StageText is... troublesome... at best)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my rudimentary widget from a [Button](http://wiki.starling-framework.org/feathers/button) subclass to a [TextInput](http://wiki.starling-framework.org/feathers/text-input) with editor factory returning a custom flash.text.TextField that has it's SoftKeyboardEvent.SOFT_KEYBOARD_ACTIVATING being nixed via preventDefault().

I now have most of what I wanted from my basic text input functionality in that I now have a text widget I can click in and select text and have all the simple cursor functionality I was missing.  This still prevents the flaky native-softkeyboard interaction so I think this might suffice.